# I'm currently specializing in Urology

Tags: grammaticality

If I'm currently studying to specialize in Urology, for example, is it correct to say, 
I'm specializing in Urology, or does it imply that I already did my exams and specialized in Urology?

Comment: Context, context, context  . . .

Comment: I think that it would be morally acceptable as a chat-up line (and would not give a false impression) but not on a CV.

Comment: To make the point about context more pointed, WHERE are you studying? This may be case where different regionalisations of English will carry different meanings.

Comment: I would think the present continuous implies you are studying it. I don't hang around that many doctors, but I would imagine that "I'm currently specializing in Urology" would be said by somebody who was not yet a urologist, but working on becoming one, while "I specialize in Urology" would be used by people who are already urologists.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already taken your exams and are a specialist in urology, does that mean that you're a urologist (MD)? If so, then you should say "I'm a urologist".

If you're currently studying to specialize in urology, does that mean that you're a medical student who wants to become a urologist once you graduate from med school, or that you're an MD who's changing specialties from, say, orthopedics to urology? If so, then you should say either "I'm currently studying to specialize in urology" or "I'm studying to become a urologist" (or something similar).

The present progressive "I'm currently studying" means that you're studying urology now; "to specialize in urology" implies that you aren't yet a urologist.

Comment: Let's say I'm a graduate from med school and currently studying to specialize in Urology, is it incorrect to say " I'm currently specializing in Urology" ?

Comment: No, it's not incorrect. So if you're an intern or a resident in urology, then you can say "I'm currently specializing in urology". When you become a board-certified urologist, you can say "I'm a urologist", but you can also say that you're a urologist if you're a resident in urology.